# Always getting the same value from inflated layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inflate

I am inflating a layout on a button click,as many time as button clicked,This Layout is having edittexts,I want to get all that values into hashmap,But all time i get the only first value into hashmap,Loop is running number of layouts inflated times,but all time getting the values from first layout only,My code is as below,please help me for it,
**code**

```
ArrayList<ViewGroup> listOfViewGroups;
LinearLayout listitems;
onCreate(){
listitems = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_list);
listOfViewGroups = new ArrayList<ViewGroup>();
et_item_id = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.et_item_id);
        et_desc = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.et_desc);
        et_qty = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.et_qty);
        et_unit_prize = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.et_unit_prize);
        et_amt = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.et_amt);

        buttonRemove.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        et_qty.addTextChangedListener(textwatcher);
        et_unit_prize.addTextChangedListener(textwatcher);

        listitems.addView(addView);

        listOfViewGroups.add(listitems);

add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener)){
@Override
onClick(){
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_descs, null);
            ImageView buttonRemove = (ImageView) addView.findViewById(R.id.iv_del);
            et_item_id = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.et_item_id);
            et_desc = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.et_desc);
            et_qty = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.et_qty);
            et_unit_prize = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.et_unit_prize);
            et_amt = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.et_amt);

            et_qty.addTextChangedListener(textwatcher);
            et_unit_prize.addTextChangedListener(textwatcher);
listitems.addView(addView);
            listOfViewGroups.add(listitems);
}

}
    public String urlgenerater() {

            String paramPass = null;

            // get each ViewGroup
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfViewGroups.size(); i++) {
                ViewGroup vg = listOfViewGroups.get(i);
                // get each EditText containing the amount
                EditText item_id = (EditText) vg.findViewById(R.id.et_item_id);
                EditText desc = (EditText) vg.findViewById(R.id.et_desc);
                EditText unitprice = (EditText) vg.findViewById(R.id.et_unit_prize);
                EditText qty = (EditText) vg.findViewById(R.id.et_qty);
                // get the string entered in the EditText
                // change to a double
                System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::::::::::::ITEM _ID:::::::::::::::::::::;;" + item_id.getText().toString());
                System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::::::::::::DESCRIPTION:::::::::::::::::::;;" + desc.getText().toString());
                System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::::::::::::UNIT PRICE::::::::::::::::::::;;" + unitprice.getText().toString());
                System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::::::::::::QUANTITY:::::::::::::::::::::;;" + qty.getText().toString());

                descMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                descMap.put("item", item_id.getText().toString());
                descMap.put("up", unitprice.getText().toString());
                descMap.put("desc", desc.getText().toString());
                descMap.put("qty", qty.getText().toString());

                System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::MAP VALUES::::::::::" + descMap);

                descList.add(descMap);

                paramPass = paramPass + "&item_name[" + i + "]=" + item_id.getText().toString() + "&qty[" + i + "]=" + qty.getText().toString() + "&desc[" + i + "]=" + desc.getText().toString()
                        + "&unit_price[" + i + "]=" + unitprice.getText().toString();

            }

            return paramPass;
        }
    }
```

Comment: post the code where you add the viewgroups to hashmap

Comment: you might have added the same view to listOfViewGroups.

Comment: do linearlayout has vertical orientation? you may need to change it to vertical to see all added view.

Comment: Can you try using a listview and a Basic Adapter instead?It will ease your work and provide you a much more cleaner code to access values

Comment: @nr4bt-Problem is n ot with view,I am getting perfect Layout,but when i try to retrieve inflated layouts' values it gives me same values.